# Данные не сохраняются в Realtime Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase

Подключил realtime database к своему проекту в android studio, создал таблицу в базе данных, пытаюсь добавить туда строку. Код:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

Но оно почему то не добавляет ничего в БД. Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в том что при создании вы выбирали не стандартный сервер который стоит по умолчанию, а тот который в Европе или в Азии если это так то вам нужно скопировать ссылку на него и вставить в `FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your_link")`. Вторая возможная проблема это то что в ваших правилах безопасности стоят значения false и это не разрешает записывать и читать ваши данные и в таком случаи измените их на true только учтите перед выпуском приложения обязательно напишите какие-то правила чтобы вашу информацию никто кроме вас не смог изменять или читать информацию из всей вашей базы данных подробнее [здесь](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

Comment: Мне помогло это, спасибо